# how does handleURL in the Ember Router translate into a transition?

Tags: ember.js

When reviewing the Ember Router, I had a look at the `handleURL` method, but how does this end up creating a transition to the new route? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Are you diving into the [source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L156)?

Comment: @PatsyIssa yeah, have just been looking into the source and have found what im looking for in the compiled vendor.js , just trying to determine where the original code is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dove some more into the source, the handleURL method ends up here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.7.0/packages/router/lib/main.js

Specifically it hands off to the `router['handleURL']` and passes the URL given as an argument. This is then what drives the transition to the new route.